# Marionette nested module has a maximum layer?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I am working with Marionette,
I am using modules to organize functions, how ever I encountered an error that the module becomes `undefined`. The test case is:

```
app.module('MainApp', function (MainApp, app, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) {
});

app.module('MainApp.TestApp', function (TestApp, app, Backbone, Marionette, $, _){
    TestApp.Controller = {
        test : function (){
            console.log('test');
        }
    };
});

app.module('TestApp.TestApp2', function (TestApp2, app, Backbone, Marionette, $, _){
    TestApp2.Controller = {
        test : function (){
            console.log('test2');
        }
    };
});
```

If I call `app.MainApp.TestApp.Controller.test();` it prints `test` correctly. However if do `app.MainApp.TestApp.TestApp2.Controller.test();` it shows `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Controller' of undefined`

Does this mean that I can only use 3 layer nested module in Marionette? Or where I made the mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i know there is no documented limit for nested modules depth.

You should define sub-modules with following naming pattern:

`Application.Module.SubModule`

So your mistake is that you have defined `TestApp2` without `MainApp`.

Correct way:

```
app.module('MainApp.TestApp.TestApp2', function (TestApp2, app){
    TestApp2.Controller = {
        test : function (){
            console.log('test2');
        }
    };
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rLta7517/)